# helm chart stable/logstash - doesnt see elasticsearch in same ns

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I've installed for local testing elasticsearch and logstash which seems to not see the local es - any idea how es is seen within the cluster/ns ?

```
helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co
helm install elastic/elasticsearch --name elasticsearch
```

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
helm install stable/logstash --name logstash -f logstash.yaml
```

this is the error message:

```
[2020-01-29T07:40:43,368][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch.cluster.local:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch.cluster.local:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch.cluster.local: Name or service not known"}
```

The logstash.yaml is - (full config can be checked with `helm inspect values stable/logstash`) i trimmed everything and left what's important i presume.

```
elasticsearch:
  host: elasticsearch.cluster.local
  port: 9200
```

---

EDIT:
Everything works when I put the IP of the pod of elasticsearch master - problem is there are 3 pods and I'd rather hit the dns/fqdn of it rather than particular instance - any idea how it's visible inisde the cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out how the dns's work

first find out the service name :

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
elasticsearch-master            ClusterIP   10.140.10.26   <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP   108m
elasticsearch-master-headless   ClusterIP   None           <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP   108m
kibana-kibana                   ClusterIP   10.140.10.55   <none>        5601/TCP            108m
```

see on what namespace it is

```
$ kubectl get ns
NAME               STATUS        AGE
default            Active        1d
kube-public        Active        1d
kube-system        Active        1d
monitoring         Active        1d
```

and it will be visible from other pods through the

```
elasticsearch-master.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: sorry, because I have the exact same issue, could you please elaborate a little bit more?